# Error "cannot apply field access to type Text" when using Text.Combine string in SQL as parameter

Tags: powerquery, m

I am trying to get a list of orders from an Excel table, convert it to a comma delimited list, and use the value in an 'IN' clause of a SQL 'WHERE' statement.

The result of the list looks good and is of the expected type. When I try to use it in the SQL, I get the error

> Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type Text.
> Details:
> Value='1','2','3','4','5','6'
> Key=AddedApostrophe

I thought I understood the error and made sure the column is of type Text, but I still can't get past the error. What am I missing?

Here is the M code for reference:

```
let
Source = WorkOrders,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "AddedApostrophe", each "'" & [Work Orders] & "'"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"AddedApostrophe", type text}}),
WOList = Text.Combine(#"Changed Type"[AddedApostrophe],",") in WOList
```

Then

```
let
WOList = Text.Combine(#"WorkOrders (2)"[AddedApostrophe],","),
sQuery = "select wadoco from proddta.F4801 where wadoco in (" & WOList & ")",
Source = Sql.Database("servername", "DBname", [Query= sQuery]) in Source
```

Comment: If you navigate to the `sQuery` intermediate step, what does the query editor show that string is?

Comment: Or if it doesn't get that far, what step is throwing the error?

Comment: I fixed the type Text error, but...

Note the M code. I was trying to resolve an error 

> Formula.Firewall: Query 'JDEWO' (step 'Source') references other
> queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please
> rebuild this data combination.

And while doing it, I have Text.Combine done twice. One as the last step of the first result, and the second as the first step in the second result. I removed the second one and I am now back to my original error.

Given the original problem, does anyone know how to resolve the Formula.Firewall error?

Comment: @AlexisOlson, Here is the sQuery result.select
wadoco
from proddta.F4801
where wadoco in ('1','2','3','4','5','6'). I think it will work if I can get around the Formula.Firewall error. Note, I have used parameter driven queries to this datasource before. They just haven't been in an IN clause like this.